# Lithuanian citizen going to Lithuania throught Abu Dhabi with 2 months passport validity

Tags: airport-transfer

I am a Lithuanian citizen going from Sydney to Lithuania but my passport is expiring in two months from travel day. I will travel to Lithuania to change my passport via Abu Dhabi and will only change plane and will not leave the airport or enter the country, only transfer from 1 terminal to another. Can anyone please advice if that is ok to transfer in Abu Dhabi airport with 2 months passport validity. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The 6 month rule applies only to entry, not for transiting the UAE. You will be able to transit airside, but you won't be able to pass UAE immigration.

When you arrive at AUH just follow the signs for Flight Transfer. It is approximately a 20 minute walk between the terminals.